# Commands within if condition

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, command

I am new to scripting

Can anyone help me with what is wrong with my below script. I am getting an error.

```
if `tail -2 jeevagan/sample/logs.txt | head -1 | grep "Start Outputing Report"` = TRUE && `tail -1 jeevagan/sample/logs.txt | grep "Start Outputing Report"` = TRUE

then
        echo "report error"
else
        echo "report good"
fi
```

In the logs file, i have logs such as below:

```
2016-04-07 06:57:36,248 INFO : Finished Outputing Report:, Format:EXCEL, Locale: en_IN
2016-04-07 07:06:52,812 INFO : Start Outputing Report:, Format:EXCEL, Locale: en_IN
2016-04-07 06:52:56,451 INFO : Finished Outputing Report:, Format:EXCEL, Locale: en_IN
2016-04-07 06:52:56,451 INFO : Finished Outputing Report:, Format:EXCEL, Locale: en_IN
2016-04-07 07:06:52,812 INFO : Start Outputing Report:, Format:EXCEL, Locale: en_IN
2016-04-07 07:06:52,812 INFO : Start Outputing Report:, Format:EXCEL, Locale: en_IN
2016-04-07 07:06:52,812 INFO : Start Outputing Report:, Format:EXCEL, Locale: en_IN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 'man bash' on my solaris system:

```
command1 && command2
command2 is executed if, and only if,  command1  returns  an
exit status of zero.
```

To examine the exit status run a command, then

```
echo $?
```

So

```
tail -2 log.txt | head -1 | grep "Start Outputing Report"
```

Returns 0

So you can string them together like so

```
tail -2 log.txt | head -1 | grep "Start Output" && tail -1 log.txt | grep "Start Output" && echo "report error"
```

or script them out something like

```
tail -2 log.txt | head -1 | grep "Start Output" && tail -1 log.txt | grep "Start Output" 

return=$?

if [[ $return == 0 ]]; then
    echo "report error"
else
    echo "report good"
fi
```